# IntelliJ unable to recognize schema name in CallableStatement string

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a CallableStatement like

```
CallableStatement cStmt = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call schemaName.doSomethingFunction(?) }"));
```

IntelliJ is showing error in the editor "Unable to resolve symbol 'schemaName'". Although the code executes fine but I want to remove this error.
I also have a data source setup for this schema in intelliJ. Removing the schemaName from the CallableStatement like below makes the editor green

```
CallableStatement cStmt = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call doSomethingFunction(?) }"));
```

Any hints on what setting I missed?

Comment: Why you have ' ? = ' before the call statement?

Comment: @fabfas - that is representing the return value of that sql function. Here is the example - tutorialspoint.com/can-we-call-functions-using-callable-statements-explain-with-an-example-in-jdbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [configure the data source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/connecting-to-a-database.html) for this project and [synchronize](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/cannot-find-a-database-object-in-the-database-tree-view.html#step-1-refresh-the-database-state) it so that you see this schema and this function in [Database tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/database-tool-window.html) for this data source:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work, assuming you want to register `IN` and `OUT` parameters:

```
CallableStatement cStmt = connection.prepareCall("{ call schemaName.doSomethingFunction(?,?) }"));
```

**For Example**: you can register parameters, assuming first is `IN` parameter and second is `OUT` parameter:

```
cStmt.setInt(1, 3);
cStmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
```

Comment: No, This ended up in a SQLException with wrong number of arguments